# kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords problem

Tags: image, metadata, keyword

I am developing an iPhone app in which I want to set the keywords for an image using the ImageIO framework.

Following is the code snippet that I use for setting the keywords. The problem is it does not apply the keywords to image metadata. Could someone help me out in finding the problem here?

```
NSMutableDictionary *iptcDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Test"] 
    forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords];

NSDictionary *newImageProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:iptcDictionary 
    forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary];

CGImageSourceRef imageSource=CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageURL, nil);  //imageURL is URL of source image

CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(    
    (CFMutableDataRef)newImageFileData, CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource), 1,NULL);

CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imageDestination, imageSource, 0, 
    (CFDictionaryRef) newImageProperties);

if (CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)) {
    [newImageFileData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES]; //imagePath is the path of the destination image with new metadata
}
```

Comment: Just thought this might be helpful to identify and solve the problem:
When I changed the UTI type to @"public.tiff", I could get tags added to the destination image. 
But, I want the destination image UTI type to be same as source image UTI type.

Any solutions please?

Comment: I have observed one more thing. The same code works for the desktop application.
Does anybody knows what is the problem with iPhone version of ImageIo framework?

Comment: Any update to this?  I experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here. I can edit GPSDictionary for sure, I think I can edit the Exif dictionary, but I cannot edit the IPTCDictionary. I see all the keys of the IPTCDictionary in my final Mutable Dictionary, and I basically rewrite the file the same way as you. But the key for IPTCDictionary doesn't seem to be written.

Maybe it is time for a rdar? I'll make some further tests and file mine.

Comment: Actually I tried to edit the iptc of a file where I had put some keywords. The keywords were deleted. Filed a rdar.